# how to parse json data based on a id in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to parse JSON data based on a id in flutter? I want to parse a specific data from a JSON file but the JSON file returns a list of data so I want to compare this JSON file Id to another variable to parse that specific data please help

Comment: Can you provide your code?? So we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link to generate Dart Classes for you JSON data and parse them as dart object.
After that you can get data with specific ID or any other business logic.

https://app.quicktype.io/